# Postgres Retrieve Event Before and After Searched For Event in Sequence

Tags: postgresql

I have a table full of event sequences where each event sequence has many unique events with a timestamp `ts`, a text field `event_text`, and a unique id `event_id`. I am querying the table looking for all event sequences which have an `event_text` that matches the search criteria, i.e. `test%` in the below case.

I am trying to first find each event where that text occurs and then for context find the event directly following by `ts` and directly preceding by `ts` the selected event. As you can see in the below example code, I am able to get the event directly following without too much issue, but how could I get both the event before, the selected event and the event after using the same query?

```
SELECT a.event_sequence_id, 
a.event_id, 
(ARRAY_AGG(ROW_TO_JSON((
SELECT t FROM (SELECT p.*) t)
) ORDER BY ts ASC))[1:2] AS event_sequence
FROM event_sequence_table a JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT event_sequence_id,
    ts,
    event_text,
    event_id,
    FROM event_sequence_table
    WHERE event_sequence_id = a.event_sequence_id
    AND ts >= a.ts
) p ON TRUE
WHERE event_text ILIKE 'test%'
GROUP BY a.event_sequence_id, a.event_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html) `lag()` and `lead()`. Example:

```
select 
    to_json(lag) as previous, 
    to_json(a) as found, 
    to_json(lead) as next
from (
    select
        event_text,
        lag(a) over w,
        a,
        lead(a) over w
    from event_sequence_table a
    window w as (partition by event_sequence_id order by ts)
    ) s
where event_text ilike 'test%';
```

Comment: Thanks @klin! I was unaware of those functions and this works well. My only concern is speed; this takes quite a long time to run. Is there any way to speed up that subquery - I guess I could create a CTE?

Comment: The query is only an example, as I cannot see the table definition and sample data. Using a primary key (if such exists) instead of whole rows should be faster, also an index on `(event_sequence_id, ts)` could help. On the other hand, window functions are expensive indeed. CTE won't improve performance.

Comment: CTE was to filter the big table down to only those event_sequences that matched the filter. That sped things up. Thanks again for the help - this is great!